# using foreach loop how to add sum of vlue in using php

Tags: php, foreach, foreach-loop-container

how to add each increment value using foreach loop my out put should be like

```
   1
   1+2 = 3
   1+2+3 = 5
```

my code fallows as

```
   <?php
    $value = array('1',2',3);
    foreach ($value as $prin) 
    {
    echo prin;
    }
    ?>
```

is it true to write ??

Comment: See my answer, I think that is what you need. If you don't want the = part in the first line, you'll have to add a condition before the echo statement which checks if $i = 0 and if it is, just prints $str without total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you're looking for this:

```
<?php

$values = array(1,2,3);

$values_count = count($values);

for ($i=0; $i < $values_count; $i++) { // loop $values_count number of times
    $str = ''; // this string will store the part before = in each line
    $total = 0; // initialize total to 0 after printing every line

    for ($j = 0; $j <= $i; $j++) { // loop across the first $i values in the $values array
        $str .= $values[$j] . " + "; // append to the string
        $total += $values[$j]; // add to total
    }

    $str = substr($str, 0, -3); // remove the final ' + ' from the string
    echo $str . ' = ' . $total . "\n\n"; // print line
}
```

Comment: Output for code above is: 1 = 1\n\n1 + 2 = 3\n\n1 + 2 + 3 = 6\n\n

Answer (score 0):

I think your looking for somthing like this:

```
<?php
    $value = array(1,2,3);
    $sum = 0;

    foreach ($value as $prin) 
        $sum += $prin;

    echo $sum;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be:

```
<?php
   $output = "";
   $total = 0;

   $values = array(1,2,3);
   foreach ($values as $val) 
   {
      $total += $val;
      $output += $val . " + ";
      echo $output . " = " . $total;
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

long time since I used php

```
<?php
foreach($value as $prin)
{
    $res = 0;
    for($i = 1; $i <= $prin; i++)
    {
        $res = $res + i;
        echo $i;
        if($i != $prin) echo "+"
    }
    echo "=" + res;
}
?>
```